# Python - how to re-export a file as utf-8

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv & excel files that were not correctly saved as UTF-8 so i cannot simply load them into pandas. Manually, I can open it and save as excel or csv and select utf-8 and then it works fine in pandas but I have too many files to do this manually and I don't want to replace the raw file (so overwriting it is out of the question). How can I accomplish this programmatically?

I thought of one solution could be to do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd


with open('path/to/bad_file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    text = f.read()
                
with open('fixed-temp.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(text.decode(encoding="latin-1"))
            
df = pd.read_csv('fixed-temp.csv')
```

But this leaves behind a temporary file or a new file that i don't want. I guess I could write more code to then delete this temporary file but that seems unclean and I'd rather encapsulate all this into one convenience function.

Comment: it looks like `pd.read_csv()` has an encoding parameter. Have you tried `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv',encoding='latin-1')`?

Comment: @scotscotmcc yes that does not work